# How to show that the one step method can't have consistency $p=3$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I was looking at some exercises from last years' of my Intro to numerical math class, and found this:

> Consider the following explicit one step method: $$\psi^h x=x+h \gamma_1 f(x)+ h \gamma_2 f(x+h \beta f(x))$$  Show that there is no such $\gamma_2$ that the method has $p=3$ consistency.

Unfortunately, I don't even understand the notation. Due to confusing notation in our lecture notes, there are two thing what $f$ might mean:

First: the problem is $x'=f(t,x)$

Second: the problem is $x'=\lambda x + f(t)$, with $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $f$ being the inhomogeneous part.

But none of them seems to fit here. And why would one put one $f$ into another one?

In case someone could make sense of the problem statement, I'd very much appreciate a clarification about notation and a hint to solution.

Comment: I think this is a method for solving $x'=f(x)$, seeing as $f$ has only one argument. Plugging $f$ into another is a natural thing to do: $x+h\beta f(x)$ is a kind of prediction of where the solution is going, and then we compute $f$ there. This is a kind of RK2 method. ... Do you know what $p=3$ consistency means?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: $p$-order consistency, meaning that the local truncation error is $O(h^{p+1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the method cannot achieve certain precision in general, it suffices to exhibit an equation for which it does not do it. The world's favorite equation for this purpose is $x'=\lambda x$. In practice $x'=x$ is usually enough. Let's start from $x_0=1$, so the exact solution is $x(t)=e^t$. The numerical method gives
$$
\psi^h x=1+h \gamma_1 + h \gamma_2 (1+h \beta ) = 1+(\gamma_1+\gamma_2)h + \beta\gamma_2 h^2
\tag1$$
whereas the exact solution at $x=h$ is equal to 
$$
1+ h +\frac12 h^2 + \frac16 h^3 + \dots
\tag2$$
By choosing $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\beta$ we can easily match (1) and (2) up to $O(h^3)$. But $O(h^4)$ is unattainable, since (1) lacks the cubic term.

---

By the way, where did we get the quadratic form in (1) from? It came from "plugging $f$ into itself", that is using the output of $f$ to calculate a point at which $f$ is to be evaluated. A higher-order  method would do this more than once.